# make hibernate generate a foreign key constraint without @OneToOne @OneToMany etc

Tags: java, hibernate

suppose i have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class A {
   @Basic
   public UUID getBId();
}

@Entity
public class B {
   @Id
   public UUID getId();
}
```

entity A keeps bId in one of table A's columns.
i would like for hibernate to generate the foreign key constraint (from A to B) and yet i really wouldnt like to make the relasionship explicit (entity B is linked to a great deal of entities this way, most of which are seldom used and i would very much like to avoid the overhead)

Comment: If you make the association lazy-loaded, there won't be much overhead. Why don't you simply create the FK yourself, with a line of SQL?

Comment: @ForeignKey is meant to go alongside \@OneToOne etc - so no go